# How to join multiple tables, 1st table is returned ( file_id ) and 2nd table is file_list (file_no)?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to join two tables. 1st table is named "returned" with field( file_id) and 2nd table is named "file_list". Both tables field 'file_id' and 'file_no' share the same value.

file_list table

```
+---+---------+------------------+-------+
|ID | File ID | File Desc.       | Status|
+---+---------+------------------+-------+
|8  | 400/3   | 1 - Test 1 400/3 |       |
+---+---------+------------------+-------+
```

Returned table

```
+---------+-----------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| File ID | File NAME       | Employee NAME | Date BORROW | Date RETURN |File STATUS |
+---------+-----------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| 400/3   | 1 - Test 1 400/3| Syuhada       | 2019-06-19  | 2019-06-18  | Returned   |
+---------+-----------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

I'm trying to send the status from returned table to file_list table

```
while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
?>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><?php echo $result["id"];?></div></td>
    <td><?php echo $result["file_no"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $result["file_desc"];?></td>
    <td>
      <div align="center">
        <?php
            /*$file_ID = "SELECT file_no FROM file_list";*/
            $sql = "SELECT * From returned
                    INNER JOIN file_list
                    ON returned.file_id = file_list.file_no;";
            $resultRet = $dbConn->query($sql);
            while($rs=$resultRet->fetch_assoc()){
              ?>
              <?php echo $rs["status"]; ?>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
      </div>
    </td>
```

Comment: please add the table schema. Also, for the second query, you need to add a WHERE condition to filter by the `$result["file_no"]`

Comment: The problem is query or php? what would you like to get from the query? Can you add an example in [plain text](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables)

Comment: What's the problem with the given query?

Comment: it does not echo the status

Answer (score 1):

As you need only the file status from the **Returned table**, you can use the following query:

`$sql = "SELECT * From returned
    WHERE file_id = " . $result["file_no"];`

I suppose that the first query return rows from **file_list** table.

Inner Join are useful when you need to get data from multiple tables in one query.

If you still want to use JOIN, the query would be like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * From returned
                INNER JOIN file_list
                ON returned.file_id = file_list.file_no AND returned.file_id = " . $result["file_no"] ;
```

**EDIT**

With Prepared Statements, only the piece of code to display the file status (with and without JOIN).

```
<td>
    <div align="center">
      <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM returned
                    WHERE file_id = ?";

        $sql_join = "SELECT * FROM returned
                        INNER JOIN file_list
                        ON returned.file_id = file_list.file_no AND returned.file_id = ?";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql_join);
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $result["file_no"]);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while($rs = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $rs["status"];
        }
        $stmt->close();
      ?>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: @Dharman as data are comming directly from database there is no SQL injection. For sure, there is a better way to write this sql